Why mutual inductance be less than or equal to geometric mean of self inductances of coils?
I understand when coils are coupled together the leakage of flux into surroundings causes mutual inductance to be less than self ones but why it has to be less than or equal to geometric mean of the self inductance?

I'd have answered this but I think this website answers your question well enough. Please read and then post if you do not understand something: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/inductor/mutual-inductance.html

thanks for giving me a new perspective, still I can't understand physical meaning of geometric mean in the equation.
